# Void JS Click in Pop-up area of "lightbox"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm making a super simple "lightbox" that pops up with a dialog box, and a dimmed background.

My problem is, I want the overlay to disappear when the user clicks on the dimmed background, but not if they click in the dialog box area.

My approach so far has been this:

I added a class with "display:none;" to the the wrapper so it would disappear if clicked. Of course, if you click in the #dialogBox this makes the overlay disappear as well. Is there any way to tell it to return the click false in the dialogBox area? Or a better way to approach this?

```
<div id="overlay" onclick="$(this).addClass('displayNone');">
    <div id="dialogBox">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
</div><!-- /#overlay -->
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the inline `onclick` attribute/handler, and bind the event in JavaScript:

```
$("#overlay").on("click", function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest("#dialogBox").length) {
        $(this).addClass('displayNone');
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/A7rNE/

This will check if the `click` came from anywhere within the `#dialogBox` element - if it didn't (note the `!` in the `if` statement), it runs the `.addClass()` part.

References:

- `.on()`: http://api.jquery.com/on/
- `.closest()`: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: @user2124775 No problem :) Let me know if you need any more help with it!

Answer (score 1):

This should prevent the click event from bubbling up to whatever element handles closing the lightbox:

```
$('#dialogBox').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```